# Utilising the pygame.mixer.music.get_endevent()

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, event-handling

I want a `tkinter` label to show nothing when a sound effect has finished.

I've been researching the www on how to create/initialise/catch the end of music event with no luck.

```
def play_btn():

    if mixer.music.get_busy():

         mixer.music.fadeout(1000)

    snd_fyl.set(snd_list.get(ACTIVE))
    mixer.music.load(snd_dir+"/"+snd_list.get(ACTIVE)+"mp3")
    mixer.music.play()

def stop_btn():

    mixer.music.stop()

    clear_label()

def clear_label():

    snd_fyl.set("")

snd_lbl1 = LabelFrame(MainWindow, text="Sound effect playing", labelanchor=N)


snd_playing_lbl = Label(snd_lbl1, width=40, textvariable=snd_fyl)
```

---

Obviously play_btn function plays a sound effect from a list.

The `stop_btn` function prematurely halts the sound effect and clears the label.

The `clear_label` function has been created in readiness for the `end_of_song` event

Comment: as for me you have to first use [set_endevent()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) to inform `pygame` what event/information it should send when music has finished. And later you can get this event in standard `for event in pygame.event.get()` to run function which will clear label. But this mean you have to run at the same time `pygame` loop and `tkitner` `mainloop()`. Or you will have to use `tkinter` `after(milliseconds, callback)` to run function which periodically will run `for event in pygame.event.get()`

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `set_endevent()` to set value which it will send to event queue when music has finished.

```
MUSIC_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_END)
```

And then you can test it in event loop

```
if event.type == MUSIC_END:
    print('music end event')
```

It will print text when music has finished - but not when you stop it or pause it.

BTW: on Linux I see this text few milliseconds before it ends playing music.

---

Full working example - but without `tkinter`

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

MUSIC_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_END)

pygame.mixer.music.load('sound.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == MUSIC_END:
            print('music end event')

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # play again
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example with `tkinter`

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk

def check_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MUSIC_END:
            print('music end event')
            label['text'] = ''

    root.after(100, check_event)

def play():
    label['text'] = 'playing'
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

# --- main ---

pygame.init()    

MUSIC_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_END)
pygame.mixer.music.load('sound.wav')

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=play)
button.pack()

check_event()
root.mainloop()

pygame.quit()
```