# tkinter button struck at pressed state

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

here is my code to play mp3 files one after the other. but the problem is that, though the songs are playing one after another the tkinter window is struck and is unresponsive. so, is there a way to solve this issue or please suggest a correct way to play mp3 files in loop. thankyou!!

```
import pygame
import time
from tkinter import *
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
screen = Tk()


def play():
    my_music = [] # list cotaining name of songs.mp3
    i = len(my_music)
    while i != 0:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(f'D://sounds//{my_music[len(my_music) - i]}')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        audio = MP3(f'D://sounds//{my_music[len(my_music) - i]}')
        length = audio.info.length
        time.sleep(length)  # sleep untill the song is played totally and then continue 
        i -= 1
        
        
play_button = Button(screen, text='play', command=play)
play_button.pack()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your window is stuck because you are in the loop and tkinter can't update. Get rid of the loop and use whatever event that fires at the end of each song to cue the next song. Maybe this link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630700/utilising-the-pygame-mixer-music-get-endevent

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(...)` will block the tkinter mainloop from updating the GUI.  You can use `after()` to replace the while loop and `time.sleep(...)`:

```py
def play(i=0):
    music_dir = "D:/sounds"
    my_music = [...] # list containing name of songs.mp3
    n = len(my_music)
    song = f'{music_dir}/{my_music[i]}'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    if i < n-1:
        audio = MP3(song)
        length = audio.info.length
        # schedule the next song
        screen.after(int(length*1000), play, i+1)
```