# I need help by creating a loop in Pygame

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, pygame, audio-player

I have the following Code

```py
def play_music():
    song = playlist.get(ACTIVE)
    next_one = playlist.curselection()
    next_one = next_one[0]+1
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        playlist.selection_clear(0,END)
        playlist.activate(next_one)
        playlist.select_set(next_one,last=None)
        song = playlist.get(ACTIVE)
        pygame.mixer.music.queue(song)
```

When I run the Code, then it plays a song and after that it plays the next song in the playlist. But I want to implement this into a loop. It should queue the next song, as much songs it has in the playlist (i.e: I have 5 songs in the playlist, then I want, that I only have to press the Play-Button once and after that it plays all 5 songs, one by one.)

A Picture of my Program:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Gch.png
I hope you can help me. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: music has [set_endevent](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) which you can use to send event when it ends playing - and this event you can catch in main loop `for event in pygame.event.get():` to run some function which add sound again to queue.

Comment: you have to run `for event in pygame.event.get():` together with `root.mainloop()` and this can make problem. Running it in `play_music` is useless because this loop has to run ALL time - like `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: usinf only `for event in pygame.event.get():` also is useless because you may get different events and you have to check `if event.type == ...: ...your code...` but first it need to define `pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(...)` because without `set_endevent(...)` it will not send this event. It seems you never write game in `PyGame`

Comment: See: [python 3.x - Utilising the pygame.mixer.music.get_endevent() - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630700/utilising-the-pygame-mixer-music-get-endevent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example from my answer for [Utilising the pygame.mixer.music.get_endevent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630700/utilising-the-pygame-mixer-music-get-endevent)

It creates own event `MUSIC_END` and assing it to music [endevent](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html).

Later it loads one song and adds next song to queue.

When first song will finished then it will generate/send event `MUSIC_END`. But this need to run all time `for event in pygame.event.get()` to catch this event and run code which will add next song to queue.

When it will finish next song then it will generate/send again event `MUSIC_END` which loop will catch and add again song to queue.

With more songs it need to keep all songs on list and remeber which song from list it has to add to queue.

**EDIT:**

Version which works with list of songs and changes also text on label.

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk

def check_event():
    global current_song
    global next_song
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MUSIC_END:
            print('music end event')

            # calculate index for current song (which was takes from queue) 
            #current_song = (current_song + 1) % len(songs)
            current_song = next_song
            
            # add title for current song
            label['text'] = songs[current_song]
            
            # calculate index for next song            
            next_song = (current_song + 1) % len(songs)
            
            # add to queue next song
            pygame.mixer.music.queue(songs[next_song])

    # run again after 100ms (0.1s)
    root.after(100, check_event)

def play():
    label['text'] = songs[current_song]
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

# --- main ---

songs = [
    'audio1.wav',
    'hello-world-of-python.mp3',
]

current_song = 0
next_song = 1

pygame.init()    

# define new type of event
MUSIC_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1

# assign event to `endevent`
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_END)

# play first song
pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[current_song])

# calculate index for next song            
next_song = (current_song + 1) % len(songs)

# add to queue next song
pygame.mixer.music.queue(songs[next_song])

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=play)
button.pack()

check_event()
root.mainloop()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: So, I have now copied your Code here and edited it, so that it works for me. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve the problem in my own code. So now I have to write everything from new again :(. But thank you for your help. Also, I don't understand every element of your code, maybe because I'm too new into programming. Maybe I will understand it in about a half - to a year.

Comment: without full code we can only show own example how to use it. You may have more complex code and it may need more complex solution.